# QVT transformation applied to UML (XMI) models exported from Rhapsody

Tags: model, eclipse-emf, rhapsody, qvt

I guess this is quite a strange question about models transformation. 
I am starting from a UML 2.2 model defined with Rhapsody (IBM/Telelogic) and exported in XMI by means of the Rhapsody XMI toolkit. I have succesfully opened it with Topcased (The Eclipse based UML/Sysml modeling environment). I have therefore applied a QVT transformation to it, aimed at creating a new UML model with a specific subset of entities. 
Unfortunately i have not found the right way to retrieve entities description (i.e. class and methods description) i wrote in Rhapsody. I have noticed these are present in the XMI file as RhapsodyProfile:RhpModelElement tags and  descriptionHTML or descriptionRTF attributes. However in the QVT transformation they are neither referrable as stereotypes nor as annotations. It is very important to me not to loose this information. Is there any of you who faced the same issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I guess I could answer my question. 
I have actually not found the way to do that but you can work around it by using tag in Rhapsody. They are exported as Stereotypes applied to the tagged element. You can thus manage them in QVT.

Bye

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Probably these comments are not exported in a "standard" XMI format so Topcased ignores them when loading the model.

Comment: They are actually not ignored. I can see them in the TopCased UML editor although they are expressed in some sort of "Rhapsody profile". Here is some doc about it http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.rhapsody.oem.pdf.doc/pdf/XMI_Toolkit_Mapping_Rules_Overview.pdf

The problem is that, since I do not have the profile meta-model i can not manage these entities in the QVT transformation. 
Moreover even if I could I can not see how they relate to the UML entities they actually refer to