# How to transform a topcased sysml model into a rhapsody sysml model?

Tags: model, transform, eclipse-emf, xmi, rhapsody

I'm trying to convert existing Topcased SYSML models to Rhapsody SYSML models.
It is possible to convert UML models with the Rhapsody XMI Toolkit.
Unfortunately it doesn't work with SYSML models because topcased uses another sysml profile than rhapsody. A bidirectional transformation would be even better, but topcased->rhapsody is more important. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: I found this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005002/qvt-transformation-applied-to-uml-xmi-models-exported-from-rhapsody

Answer (score 0):

well the "easiest" thing you can do is:
 - make a simple SysML model in Rhapsody with few blocks, aggregatios, dependencies, ports, connectors and the elements you want to import from your topcased models;
 - export this model by means of the Rhapsody XMI toolkit in order to have an example of the XML format in which you need to turn your original Topcased models;
 - define an Acceleo transformation that transforms your original model elementes (i.e. Blocks, ports, etc.) into an XML conform to the Rhapsody XMi schema;
 - import the obtained files in Rhapsody.

Acceleo is an Eclipse implementation of the OMG standard MOF Models To Text Transformation Language. You can find it already available in TopCased.

This procedure will import the model not the diagrams. You should then create them on you own directly in Rhapsody.

I hope this helps you